Assistance Needed with GEANT4 Simulation of Varian TrueBeam
I am a trainee medical physicist from Karachi, Pakistan. I am doing a project based on GEANT4 Monte Carlo simulation. For that i wanted to replicate a Varian Truebeam model on GEANT4.Is there any open source available such as GAMMORA so that i can work on.
I download the GAMMORA (A TrueBeam model for Geant4/GATE) and installed it. When I run the pre-existing example of medical linac available in GEANT4 it shows me the error regarding water density. Is there anyway I can resolve this issue?.
Looking forward to your positive responses. Thanks
I download the GAMMORA (A TrueBeam model for Geant4/GATE) and installed it. When I run the pre-existing example of medical linac available in GEANT4 it shows me the error regarding water density. Is there anyway I can resolve this issue?.

How is this question programming-related? Asking for external resources on StackOverflow is explicitly off-topic

What version of geant do you use.? Platform?

I am using Geant4-11.2.2 on Ubuntu 20.04
